# How can I create a simple function?

Tags: php, function

Why is this working...

```
$animal='';
    $animal .= "You edited this animal: ";
    if ($data['horse'] != $horse){
        $animal .= 'Name from "'.$data['horse'].'" into "'.$horse.'"';
    }   
    $sql = "INSERT INTO animal (animal,id) values(?,?)";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($animal,$id));
```

(Result: "You edited this animal: Mustang into Marwari")

...but this...

```
$animal='';
$animal .= "You edited this animal: ";  
function animal_func($label, $orig, $edit) {
    if ($orig != $edit){
        $animal .= $label.' from "'.$orig.'" into "'.$edit.'"';
    }
}
animal_func("Name",$data['horse'],$horse);

$sql = "INSERT INTO animal (animal,id) values(?,?)";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($animal,$id));
```

(Result: "You edited this animal: ")

... is not working

Comment: Just to learn, why did I get a downvote for my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the scope of the $animal variable.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

You need to pass an return the $animal var :
/* if you need this only once, outside is better */
    $animal .= "You edited this animal: ";

```
function animal_func($label, $orig, $edit, $animal) { 
    if ($orig != $edit){
        $animal .= $label.' from "'.$orig.'" into "'.$edit.'"';
    return $animal;
    }
}


$animal = animal_func("Name",$data['horse'],$horse,$animal);
```

You can also do that, perhaps more readable :

```
function animal_func($label, $orig, $edit, $animal) {
    if ($orig != $edit) {
        $animal .= $label.' from "'.$orig.'" into "'.$edit.'"';
        return $animal;
    }
}

$animal = "You edited this animal: ";
$animal = animal_func("Name",$data['horse'],$horse,$animal);
```

After another read (this is better):

```
function animal_func($label, $orig, $edit) {
    if ($orig != $edit) {
        return $label.' from "'.$orig.'" into "'.$edit.'"';
    }
}

$animal = "You edited this animal: ".animal_func("Name",$data['horse'],$horse);
```

Comment: Thank you, this seem to work. But I cannot get in run with the first part of my code. Your version is only giving the result `Mustang into Marwari` and not `"You edited this animal: Mustang into Marwari"`

Comment: Yes, you have to add the first part of you string, response edited

Comment: Oh I figured it out. I just need to change `$animal = animal_func("Name",$data['horse'],$horse,$animal);` into `$animal .= animal_func("Name",$data['horse'],$horse,$animal);`

Comment: Don't you need the "point" to make it work? Like `$animal .= ` instead of `$animal = ` for your second example?

Comment: $animal is passed to the function, the function take it and add the text, with the concatenation operator ( . )  then Return it, so the value returned is the string contains by $animals before the calling, and all string added in the function.
If you use .= you add "You edited this animal: " twice  
I add another way to write the code, I think better, because you don't need the $animal var in the function

Answer (score 1):

Put this animal into function

```
function animal_func($label, $orig, $edit) {
    $animal='';
    $animal .= "You edited this animal: ";
    if ($orig != $edit){
        $animal .= $label.' from "'.$orig.'" into "'.$edit.'"';
    }
}
animal_func("Name",$data['horse'],$horse);
```

or

Declare

```
global $animal='';
$animal .= "You edited this animal: ";
```

Comment: Thank you But I need ` $animal .= "You edited this animal: ";` only one time, but later `$label.' from "'.$orig.'" into "'.$edit.'"'` many times. This means `You edited this animal: ` should not be part of the function. Do you know how I mean it?

Comment: Declare this variable as global and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the scope of your `$animal` inside your `animal_func()` is limited to that function only.

What you need to do is pass `$animal` as reference variable in your `animal_func()`. So your function should look like:

```
$animal='';
$animal .= "You edited this animal: ";  
function animal_func($label, $orig, $edit, &$animal) {
    if ($orig != $edit){
        $animal .= $label.' from "'.$orig.'" into "'.$edit.'"';
    }
}
animal_func("Name",$data['horse'],$horse, $animal);
```

See [PHP manuals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for variable scope and variable pass by reference on [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion, but somehow it is not working. Nothing is stored into the database

Comment: What you get after applied this changes?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you wrote `&$animal` instead of `$animal`

Comment: I pass the variable by reference so `$animal`, thus it referenced to `$animal` which you declared at side the function.